# Select * From Table Where Name in like (wildcards)

Tags: sql, select

Is it possible to combine SQL statements such as

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y LIKE '%a%' OR Y LIKE '%b%' OR Y LIKE '%c%' OR Y LIKE '%d%'
```

with something like

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

so I don't have to write one big statement such as it is now:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y LIKE '%a%' OR Y LIKE '%b%' OR Y LIKE '%c%' OR Y LIKE '%d%')
    BEGIN
        /* code */
    END
```

Would be very nice to use something like `SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y IN LIKE ('%a%', '%b%', etc..)`
Appreciate all help and suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Check out regular expressions for the dbms you're using.

Comment: In SQL Server you can do `WHERE y LIKE '%[a-d]%'`. But looks like a poor database design to me.

Comment: Which DMS product are you using?

Comment: the real question is: what are you doing in the `if` part? why not simply attach that WHERE clause to whatever you do inside there?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for your problem ,try and let me know if still there is issue.

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y LIKE '%[a-d]%'
```

Comment: that is not going to work in standard SQL (which the `sql` tag refers to) - please mention the DBMS for which this is working

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports RegEx, you can use that. For example:

`SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y SIMILAR TO '%(a|b|c|d)%'` in PostgreSQL, and

`SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y REGEXP 'a|b|c|d'` in MySQL.

`LIKE '%[a-d]%'` **won't** work because `LIKE`s in most databases don't accept regex patterns. This will just expect the literal text `[a-d]` somewhere in the string. How each database interprets regular expression (or native pattern) varies a lot. So you need to tailor these things to your database. For example, the following will **not work** in PostgreSQL:

`SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y SIMILAR TO 'a|b|c|d'`

because PostgreSQL will expect the whole string to be 'a', 'b', 'c', or 'd'.