# SELECT WHERE in varchar with wildcard

Tags: mysql, wildcard, varchar, mysql-8.0, where-in

Lets say i have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Parts (ID int, part_number varchar(100), isActive TINYINT);
```

and these sample records

```
|ID | part_number   | isActive|
===============================
  1 | 1N3.805.327   |  1      
  2 | 1N3.805.327.B |  1
  3 | 1N3.804.108.B |  1
  4 | 1N3.804.108.C |  1
  5 | 1N3.804.107.B |  1
  6 | 1N3.804.107.C |  1
  7 | 1N3.804.106.A |  1
  8 | 1N3.804.105.A |  1
```

#### Problem

I would like to combine a `where in` clause with the wildcard `%` operator
In my [dbfiddle sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7918a5b9f4c1f2319d90030e55782e6) i tried [the string function `find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) and the [comparison operator `in()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in). Both do not work:

```
-- without wildcard the query works
SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE part_number in ('1N3.804.108.B', '1N3.804.106.A'); -- 2

-- with wildcard no records are returned
SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE part_number in ('1N3.804.108%', '1N3.804.106%'); -- 0 
SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(part_number, '1N3.804.108%,1N3.804.106%'); -- 0
```

Questions

1. I assume i could use `WHERE LEFT(part_number, 11) in ('1N3.804.108', '1N3.804.106')` But i do not know if this has any disadvantages.
2. Is there a way to use a wildcard operator with `in()`?

#### Sample records

```
INSERT INTO 
    Parts(ID, part_number, isActive)
VALUES
    (1, '1N3.805.327',1),
    (2, '1N3.805.327.B',1),
    (3, '1N3.804.108.B',1),
    (4, '1N3.804.108.C',1),
    (5, '1N3.804.107.B',1),
    (6, '1N3.804.107.C',1),
    (7, '1N3.804.106.A',1), 
    (8, '1N3.804.105.A',1);
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561211/select-from-table-where-name-in-like-wildcards but i am hesitant to use regular expressions. It seems they are not the right tool here.

Comment: Normalising your data would make this kind of thing more efficient

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to use IN instead of just a series of OR'ed LIKE conditions?

Comment: Hi David, it seems inconvenient to add 10 to 20 OR'ed LIKE conditions: `SELECT p.* FROM Parts p WHERE part_number like '1N3.804.108%' OR part_number like '1N3.804.106%' OR ..... OR ..... OR ....;`

Comment: How about `SUBSTRING_INDEX` like `SELECT p.* FROM Parts p WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(part_number,'.',3) in ('1N3.804.108', '1N3.804.106');`?

Answer (score 1):

Use REGEXP for that, when you want to use OR

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Parts (ID int, part_number varchar(100), isActive TINYINT);
> INSERT INTO 
>     Parts(ID, part_number, isActive)
> VALUES
>     (1, '1N3.805.327',1),
>     (2, '1N3.805.327.B',1),
>     (3, '1N3.804.108.B',1),
>     (4, '1N3.804.108.C',1),
>     (5, '1N3.804.107.B',1),
>     (6, '1N3.804.107.C',1),
>     (7, '1N3.804.106.A',1), 
>     (8, '1N3.804.105.A',1);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROm Parts WHeRE part_number REGEXP '^(1N3.804.108|1N3.804.106)'
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | part_number   | isActive
> -: | :------------ | -------:
>  3 | 1N3.804.108.B |        1
>  4 | 1N3.804.108.C |        1
>  7 | 1N3.804.106.A |        1
> ```

MySQL Can only UNION  a certain number of tables. i think it is about 53.

With an index on partnumber, this will be the fastest.

> ```
> SELECT * FROm Parts WHeRE part_number REGEXP '^1N3.804.108'
> UNION all
> SELECT * FROm Parts WHeRE part_number REGEXP '^1N3.804.106'
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | part_number   | isActive
> -: | :------------ | -------:
>  3 | 1N3.804.108.B |        1
>  4 | 1N3.804.108.C |        1
>  7 | 1N3.804.106.A |        1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROm Parts WHeRE part_number LIKE '1N3.804.108%'
> UNION all
> SELECT * FROm Parts WHeRE part_number LIKE '1N3.804.106%'
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | part_number   | isActive
> -: | :------------ | -------:
>  3 | 1N3.804.108.B |        1
>  4 | 1N3.804.108.C |        1
>  7 | 1N3.804.106.A |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6e809467db60c416870ac4626dd6953)*

Comment: Hi @nbk do you know if REGEX performs well even for 20 or 30 partnumbers?

Comment: Or statements never perform well, that is because an index doesn't help that much. i will add a second query, but the solution can only held 50 or so values

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to do

```
select *, 
       REGEXP_LIKE(part_number,[pattern]) as pattern_test from Parts 
where pattern_test is TRUE
```

here first you will create the pattern that you are interested in and apply it on the column you wish to apply it to. The pattern_test will return true if it matches with your pattern and then you can filter on that [where clause]

Comment: At dbfiddle.com a subquery was needed: `SELECT sq.* FROM (SELECT *, 
       REGEXP_LIKE(part_number,'^(1N3.804.108|1N3.804.106)') as pattern_test from Parts) as sq Where sq.pattern_test = 1; ` otherwise an error occurs: column pattern_test unknown.

Comment: Do you see an advantage over the answer from nbk?

Comment: yes you can add a subquery or CTE to make the unknown error go away

Comment: Is your sample running on your server?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59b99db329bcb460bfa0855e177bbcff here is an example where selecting for only where pattern matched